# Managing managed switches

Tags: switch, dell, dell-powerconnect, manage

I have a number of Dell PowerConnect switches. I've successfully setup various 'trunks' and vLANs and all working sweet. But one thing annoys me. I can't seem to 'manage' my switches from my laptop as I am on a particular subnet (vLAN12 10.0.12.x) and my switches are all setup to be managed on the 10.0.1.x and its not routable. I need to go down and plug my laptop physically into each switch - which is a pain in the arse.

Any ideas or thoughts?? .... Other than I'm an idiot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options come to mind:

1. Make the 10.0.1.0/24 network routed via your router.
2. Give your switches 10.0.1.0/24 management IPs.
3. Have a server or one swtich on both the 10.0.1.x network and the 10.0.12.x network and use that as a management box that you ssh  or remote desktop into. Then connect to all the switches from that box. The management box could also have a some sort of serial multiplexer and be connected to each switch's port -- but that would be bit out of the norm.

Comment: Cheers Guys, will do a bit of playing around with these sugegstions ;)

Comment: my current switches all use 10.0.1.x addresses. That subnet I am assuming is in VLAN1 the default vlan and therefor unroutable?!?

Comment: No VLAN is unroutable, but you will need a router set up to route between the different VLANs in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't route your management network? Between firewalling and management-access ACLs on the switches, you should be able to lock access down sufficiently.